# IUPAC name for citric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds

I wonder what the name is of the following structure is:
[image]

I think it's something like 3-hyrodxypentanoic diacid
However, I wasn't able to find how to name a side chain if it contains a $\ce{COOH}$ group.

Maybe I'm completely wrong, I hope someone can tell me how to name this structure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*, the order of seniority of classes in decreasing order of seniority is as follows.

> (…)
>   7. acids
>   (…)
>   17. hydroxy compounds (includes alcohols and phenols)
>   (…)

Thus, the carboxylic acid group has priority to be cited as a suffix.

Systematic names of carboxylic acids are generally formed using the suffix ‘oic acid’ or ‘carboxylic acid’ or the prefix ‘carboxy’.

The relevant rule in this case reads as follows:

> **P-65.1.2.2.1** If an unbranched chain is linked to more than two carboxy groups, all
>   carboxy groups are named from the parent hydride by substitutive use of the suffix
>   ‘carboxylic acid’, preceded by the appropriate numerical prefix ‘tri’, ‘tetra’ etc. and
>   appropriate locants.

Note that the suffix ‘carboxylic acid’ expresses the substituent group $\ce{-COOH}$. Thus, the name of unsubstituted tricarboxylic acid corresponding to the compound given in the question is ‘propane-1,2,3-tricarboxylic acid’.

[image: propane-1,2,3-tricarboxylic acid]

Therefore, the preferred IUPAC name (PIN) of the complete compound given in the question is ‘2-hydroxypropane-1,2,3-tricarboxylic acid’.

[image: 2-hydroxypropane-1,2,3-tricarboxylic acid]

However, according to Subsection P-65.1.1.2.3, the name ‘citric acid’ is also retained for general nomenclature.